# Convert list of tables to matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list containing 270 tables. Each table has 3 columns and 22 rows, looking something like this:

```
                1         2         3
lx      -0.206628 -0.148405 -0.159344    
ly       0.017395  0.043114  0.027263    
lz      -0.044009  0.005597 -0.016906
...
```

I need each of these tables merged into a giant 270x66 matrix, where the rows are each table and the columns are values in the table columns. I've tried using `lapply`, `as.matrix`, and `data.matrix`. Is there some kind of combination of these that will do the trick? Or should I first convert the table into vectors, then into the matrix? I know loops are generally discouraged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a vector using `unlist` and then create a new matrix:

```
matrix(unlist(mylist), nrow = length(mylist), byrow = TRUE)
```

An example:

```
mylist <- rep(list(matrix(1:9, 3)), 3)
matrix(unlist(mylist), nrow = length(mylist), byrow = TRUE)
# 
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
# [2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
# [3,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
```

Comment: That gets me a 22x810 double matrix. Should I include some arguments in there?

Comment: Thanks for the example. I have the right amount of rows, but only one column with the same value: Numeric,66. Did I go wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

This would work too I think:

```
#create a list like you discussed
LIST <- lapply(1:270,  function(i) matrix(1:66, ncol =3))

do.call(rbind, lapply(LIST, c))
```

It works by `lapply`ing the function `c` which tells a `matrix` to become a `vector`.  Then we use `do.call` to recursively `rbind` it all together.